# How to set the breakpoints condition in batch for VS 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

How to set the breakpoints condition (such as filter thread ID) in batch for VS 2015?

I'm debugging one of the thread pool threads, and I've set many breakpoints, so I want to filter the breakpoints to one special thread ID, then I want to set the filter condition for all of the breakpoints in batch.

However I found VS2015 doesn't support it, when I want to set them all at once, the settings is disabled, like in the image below:

[image: multiple settings disabled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, there is a [new way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01xdt7cs.aspx#Anchor_1) to configure breakpoints, which is the Breakpoint Settings window. We can configure condition and action for every breakpoint through the Breakpoint Settings window. But we could not set them in batch.

There has other community who has the same requirement and he has submit this issue to Visual Studio User Voice. You can vote and add comments for this feedback. But before the user voice accepted, you still need to configure breakpoint one by one.
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/11548368-breakpoint-condition-and-action